# Can you tell from machine code if an instruction is relocatable?

Tags: assembly

According to [Assemblers And Loaders](http://www.davidsalomon.name/assem.advertis/AssemAd.html) (a 24-year old book on how assemblers work):

> ...a one-pass assembler cannot generate a relocatable object file. The
>   type of the instruction (absolute or relocatable) can be determined
>   only by examining the original source instruction. The one-pass
>   assembler loads the machine instructions directly in memory. Once in
>   memory, the instruction is just a number. By looking at a machine
>   instruction in memory, it is impossible to tell whether the original
>   instruction was absolute or relocatable.

The book gives the following pseudo code of a relocatable and an absolute instruction:

```
    JMP TO
    ...
TO: ADD 1,2
```

Where the first instruction uses the symbol `TO` and the second instruction adds the values in register '1' and register '2'.

It is my understanding that you don't need the source code to know that the machine code of the first instruction is relocatable. It should be possible to use the opcode table to determine that it's the `JMP` instruction and that it must jump to an address which needs to be relocatable.

Is my assumption correct?

Background: although the book is old, I'm reading it get a better understanding of assembly for old CPUs like the 6502 and 65816.

Comment: Really no different than your other question.  That book talks about a relocatable bit yes?  that would be machine code then.  for other instruction sets in general, was the address loaded into a register then branched to because it was an external address or just because that is how the author or compiler did it?  (vs using a pc relative offset)

Comment: Im thinking maybe you should stop reading that book.  Get a gnu toolchain (preferrably anything but x86, arm, mips, are good choices) and just compile, disassemble then link and disassemble, and ponder or even write your own tools (assembler then linker) to see how the problems are or can be solved.

Answer (score 5):

Your book is misleading, a one pass assembler, as most people would understand the term, can generate a relocatable object file by emitting special data called relocations which tell the linker/loader how to relocate the code.  The book seems to using be a particular definition of a "one pass assembler", one that by its own definition isn't capable of outputting a "relocatable object file" with relocations.

However it is true that in general you can't tell if a given machine code instruction is relocatable unless there's a set of relocations available to tell what is or isn't relocatable (and how to relocate the instructions that aren't). Certain instructions make it obvious, for example you can tell if a `JMP TO` instruction is relocatable or not based on how the destination address is encoded.  If the destination address is encoded as a relative offset to the address of the JMP instruction then it's relocatable. On the other hand, if is encoded as an absolute address the instruction isn't relocatable. In the first case the program can be relocated in memory without modifications and the JMP instruction will still jump to the same code. In the second case the JMP instruction will always jump to the same address regardless where the code has been relocated to unless the instruction is changed to jump to correct place.

In x86 assembly a concrete example of the first case would be the following:

```
0056: EB 10     JMP LO
```

The first byte in the instruction, is the opcode `EB` (the numbers I'm using here are all in hexadecimal), which indicates a near JMP instruction with a 8-bit relative offset. The second byte in the instruction is that 8-bit relative offset. It's actually relative to the start of the following instruction, so the address jumped to is `0056 + 2 + 10` or `0068`.

In 6502 assembly an example of the second case would be:

```
0056: 4C 68 00   JMP LO
```

In this case the opcode byte `4C` indicates a JMP instruction which has uses 2-byte absolute address in encoded into the instruction.  The next two bytes make up that address in little-endian byte order: `0068`.

Another easy example is something like `ADD 1,2` which only uses registers. Since there are no addresses involved the instruction can be relocated without modification because there are no addresses encoded in the instruction. The problem is with an instruction like `ADD #1000,2`, which adds the literal value 1000 to the value stored in register 2. In this case the number 1000 is encoded in the instruction, and there's no way to know if that number being used as an address or not. Out of context, there's no way to know if instruction has an encoded address within it or not.

An example like `ADD #1000,2` in 16-bit x86 assembly language would be the following:

```
0068: 81 C3 EB 03    ADD BX, 1000
```

The last two bytes of the instruction `EB 03` is the value of 1000 in decimal and is where the immediate (literal) operand of the instruction is encoded.  The instruction adds 1000 to the BX register.  It's not possible to know without more context whether 1000 is supposed to be an address or not. For example, the code might calculating the address of something located in a table starting at address 1000.

You might want to find another book, as it seems to spend a lot of time dealing with machine architectures that were obsolete 24 years ago and are completely archaic today.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ! I think in the second part of your answers there are some words missing, could you proof-read to make sure it's correct? ("Since there >no?< addresses involved the instruction >can be?< relocated without modification because there are >no?< addresses encoded in the instruction.")

Comment: With regard to the last example, I would expect the instruction byte to indicate if `EB 03` is an immediate value to be added to BX or an address where the value to be added to BX should be fetched from. How else would the CPU be able to execute such instructions correctly?

Comment: @MichielvanOosterhout In the last example I left out explaining how opcode and other operands were decoded because it's more complex than the other examples, possibly confusing things. The first byte `81` indicates that it's an immediate group 1 instruction with a 16-bit destination operand and 16-bit immediate operand. The second byte `C3` indicates that its an ADD instruction and the destination operand is BX.  I've edited the problem sentence you mentioned.

Comment: But decoding is relevant, because the fact that the bytes indicate that the instruction's first operand is a location in memory can be used to determine that the operand needs to be changed when the code is relocated. With that in mind, I still don't understand why you wrote "However it is true that in general you can't tell if a given machine code instruction is relocatable unless there's a set of relocations available to tell what is or isn't relocatable".

Comment: @MichielvanOosterhout You're mistaken. There are no bytes in in the encoding of the instruction in my last example that indicate that the first operand is a location in memory. The first operand is the register BX, which is not a location in memory. This register may or may not contain an address when the instruction is executed, but that's immaterial. The value of the first operand isn't encoded in the instruction itself, so it can't be changed, and shouldn't be changed, by modifying the instruction. It's the second operand, whose value is encoded in the instruction, that's the problem.